# Cute pdf writer and custom saving of the file

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf-generation

I am using cute pdf writer and on printing the data, i get a save as dialog box from cute pdf, however i want to access path of the file name that is about to be saved from cute pdf.

Also i want to programmatic save in my custom location.

```
foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
                       {
  if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("CPWSave")) //CPWSave.EXE
           {
                  isCutePDFSaveDialogOpened = true;                                            
              }
    }
```

I am able to detect whether cute pdf is opened or not, but not able to pro-grammatically save in my custom location. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project in codeproject that handles both detection of CutePDF process and "print to pdf" function in a specified path:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46592/Using-the-Free-CutePDF-Writer-without-User-Interve

If you don't want to bother about pinvoke in C++, you can try this open PDF writer library:

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

Comment: What's up? Did you try the code in the "Using the free CutePDF writer without user intervention" article to see if it has some good informations about how to use the free CutePDF writer without user intervention?

Comment: Sorry i am not able to convert from c++ to c#, neither i am not able to get the logic right, am still struggling with that. Thanks for checking on.